# VBScript comparison operators not working?

Tags: vbscript, comparison, operators

I feel like this is a really obvious bug but I really can't figure it out. It seems as if the comparison operators in VBScript aren't working properly. I'm writing a program in which the user enters an order amount, and this amount is compared to 1000. If I enter 200 for the order amt, the program outputs that 200 > 1000 = true.

Here is the code for my program:

```
largeOrderAmt = 1000
orderAmt = Inputbox("What is the order amount?")
Document.write(orderAmt & largeOrderAmt & (orderAmt > largeOrderAmt))

'Calculations
If orderAmt <= largeOrderAmt then
 Document.write ("if statement called <br>")
...
Else
 Document.write ("else statement called <br>")
EndIf
```

and here is the output:
200 1000True else statement called

I really don't get it. This is extremely frustrating. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the values are compared as strings:

```
"200" > "1000" = True
```

Convert your input into a number using `CInt` or `CDbl`, e.g.:

```
orderAmt = CDbl(Inputbox("What is the order amount?"))
```