# Numbers greater than 9999.99 causing problems

Tags: asp-classic

I really need some help trying to sort out some legacy code. We've got a MySQL server and an old VBScript front end doing some simple calculations. Briefly when calculation fees based on a commission percentage, if a certain percentage and fee is reached, then the fee is capped. Everything works until I get to fees in excess of £10000.00 and it goes wrong. I've got the following code. It all works except for the last line. Anything with a Commission of 15 returns 10000.00 and I can't figure this out.

```
dbLongWinAmount = FormatNumber(dbLongPPIWinAmount,2,,,0)
dbLongNetFee = (dbLongWinAmount * dbLongCommission)/100
dbLongNetFee = FormatNumber(dbLongNetFee,2,,,0)

If dbLongCommission = "30" AND dbLongNetFee >= "420.00" Then dbLongNetFee = "420.00"
If dbLongCommission = "28" AND dbLongNetFee >= "2500.00" Then dbLongNetFee = "2500.00"
If dbLongCommission = "25" AND dbLongNetFee >= "5000.00" Then dbLongNetFee = "5000.00"
If dbLongCommission = "20" AND dbLongNetFee >= "7500.00" Then dbLongNetFee = "7500.00"
If dbLongCommission = "15" AND dbLongNetFee >= "10000.00" Then dbLongNetFee = "10000.00"
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Not SQL expert, but are you sure the comparison don't compare the strings lexicographically?

Comment: [sql server - SQL string comparison, greater than and less than operators - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080187/sql-string-comparison-greater-than-and-less-than-operators) //

Comment: Do not do this, any kind of computation/comparison should happen before applying any formatting. Formatting is purely how a value is displayed.

Comment: @user202729 this is VBScript code in Classic ASP it's not SQL.

Comment: [VBScript comparison operators not working? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162991/vbscript-comparison-operators-not-working) (not vbscript expert either.)

Comment: The selected answer isn't correct. The answer is in the code, your question is why is everything over 10K returning 10K, because that is what the code is saying

If dbLongCommission = "15" AND dbLongNetFee >= "10000.00" Then dbLongNetFee = "10000.00"

Without knowing what it should return I can't help you further.